# How to set the language feedback?

Tags: php, css, twig

I am having problem setting the language feedback. What I want to do is when I select a language that it stays in a different color. I tried to work it out, but I can't.

I am a student and I started coding this year. I work with Twig and it confuses me more.

Here is my php file for detecting the language

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['lng'])){
 $lng = $_GET['lng'];
 if($lng !== '' && ($lng === 'fr' || $lng === 'en'))
  $_SESSION['langue'] = $lng;
}
if(isset($_SESSION['langue'])) $userLang = $_SESSION['langue'];
else $userLang = 'en';

  ?>
```

In the index.php I have written

```
$view->setVar('currentLang', $userLang);
```

And this is my layout.html.twig

```
    <div id="menulangue">
          <a href="index.php?page={{ currentPage }}&lng=fr" title="Français"><div class="btnlanguess {% if currentLang==fr %}active{% endif %}">Français</div></a>
      <a href="index.php?page={{ currentPage }}&lng=en" title="English"><div 
class="btnlangue {% if currentLang==en %}active{% endif %}">English</div></a>
    </div>
```

And the css file

```
.active{
   color: #F7931E;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You need to wrap _en_ and _fr_ in string delimiters - like {% if currentLang=="en" %} - otherwise it'll try and match with the _variable_ `en`

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable the debug mode of `twig`, you are currently validating `currentLang` against the variables `en` and `fr`, which don't exist. If you had the debug enabled you would get some meaningfull error message e.g.

```
#1  Type    Twig_Error_Runtime
#2  Message     Variable "fr" does not exist.
#3  At  twigfiddle:environment/5HH6HurMWRlkmM1d/twig/main.twig:5
```

The code should be,

```
<div id="menulangue">
    <a href="index.php?page={{ currentPage }}&lng=fr" title="Français"><div class="btnlanguess {% if currentLang=="fr" %}active{% endif %}">Français</div></a>
    <a href="index.php?page={{ currentPage }}&lng=en" title="English"><div class="btnlangue {% if currentLang=="en" %}active{% endif %}">English</div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! It worked.
It should have thought about it.
I don't know how to enable the debug mode.

Comment: Are you using `Twig` standalone or with another framework?

Comment: Only Twig. I am using it with Atom.

Comment: To enable debug just pass it with your current twig options, `$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('debug' => true));`

Comment: To make use of the `dump` function to verify variables, you can watch [here](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/dump.html)